# Object's ManyToMany relationship is not updated inside signals

Tags: django, django-signals, manytomanyfield

I have this singal

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Organization)
def save_tags(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    from .views import post

    text_input_tags = post.getlist('tags1')[0]
    text_input_tags = text_input_tags.strip()
    text_inputs_tags = text_input_tags.split(' ')
    for tag in text_inputs_tags:
        if not tag.startswith('#') :
            tag = '#' + tag
        tag_obj = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name = tag)[0]#.organization_set.set([obj,])
        tag_obj.save()

        instance.tags.add(tag_obj)
        print(instance.tags.all())
```

from the views I am importing the post data to use inside the signal.
There is a manytomany relationship between two models Organization and Tag.
I am trying to get some attributes from the post request and create a Tag object from them, then after that add that Tag object into the ManyToMany relationship of the instance of the Organization.
when I print the tags of the organization instance

```
print(instance.tags.all())
```

I get the added instances in the QuerySet, but it's not saved in the organization instance and I don't understand why...
I tried to make that same functionality inside a method of UpdateView of the Organization, but it did the exact same thing and didn't work.
This is the UpdateView and its methods that doesn't work with this functionality

```
class OrganizationUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Organization
    '''fields = [
        'name',
        'slug',
        'bio',
        'avatar_thumbnail',
        'location',
        'tags',
        'contact_information'
    ]'
    '''

    form_class = forms.OrganizationForm

    def get_object(self):
        obj = Organization.objects.get(slug = self.kwargs.get('slug'))
        if self.request.user not in obj.moderators.all() :
            raise exceptions.PermissionDenied()
        return obj

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        org = self.get_object()
        POST = self.request.POST.copy()
        text_input_tags = POST.getlist('tags1')[0]
        text_input_tags = text_input_tags.strip()
        text_inputs_tags = text_input_tags.split(' ')
        for tag in text_inputs_tags:
            print(tag)
            if not tag.startswith('#') :
                tag = '#' + tag
            tag_obj = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name = tag)[0]
            tag_obj.save()
            org.tags.add(tag_obj)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # same functionality in save()
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # same functionality in save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: The `post_save` runs *before* it populates the M2M relation, since it first needs to save the record to obtain a primary key. This is one of the (many) reasons why you should not use signals: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I want to implement this functionality when the Organization is updated , and it's updated through an updateview. as I said I tried to implement it inside the methods of updateview but it didn't work , where or how should I implement it ?

Comment: An `UpdateView` does not call `.save()`: it calls `form_valid()` which saves the form, it does not call a `save()` method from the `UpdateView`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I added the functionality in the form_valid() method, it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Actually all I needed to do is to implement this functionality after all the saving of the instance has been done, so the post or form_valid methods don't apply here, I needed to implement it inside a method that happens in the last parts of the updateview, my choice was inside the get_success_url, the code looks like the following:

```
    def get_success_url(self):
        org = self.get_object()
        POST = self.request.POST.copy()
        text_input_tags = POST.getlist('tags1')[0]
        text_input_tags = text_input_tags.strip()
        text_inputs_tags = text_input_tags.split(' ')
        for tag in text_inputs_tags:
            print(tag)
            if not tag.startswith('#') :
                tag = '#' + tag
            tag_obj = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name = tag)[0]  
            tag_obj.save()
            org.tags.add(tag_obj)
        return super().get_success_url()
```